# sage pay integration How to check whether a card is a credit card or debit card

Tags: c#, payment-gateway, opayo

We are using sage pay gateway to take money from our customers which is working smoothly.but we are unable to identify whether its credit or debit card when they enter the card number in our application.

Comment: Why are you trying to Identify if it's a credit or debit card? Generally if you're using a third party service you should keep the info with the third party unless you want to make your application PCI compliant

Comment: I have to agree with @johnny5 - I can say firsthand that PCI compliance is typically complicated, time-consuming, and expensive. If you can avoid it I suggest that you do - that's what you're paying the third party for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the reporting API (https://www.sagepay.co.uk/file/6946/download-document/Reporting_and_Admin_API_Integration_Guideline_31012014.pdf) to call 'getCardDetails' - just pass the first 9 digits, and Sage Pay will return whether it is a credit / debit card (among other things).